# When do universities in USA actually start reviewing PhD applications?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, united-states

I have submitted Ph.D. applications to some STEM universities in the US with a deadline on 1st December. However, I have had some updates to my CV, as a paper that I had submitted to a journal has been accepted. So I wanted to contact the universities to mention the changes. Today is 20th December, so would the review process for my application have already started? Does the admission committee start looking at the applications before the Christmas break, or do they start after the holidays?

Comment: I understand the linked duplicate does not entirely answer the letter of your question. However, I think linking it as a duplicate is better than closing it as "depending on individual factors" or whatever else. The simple fact is that no one can know, and the answer on that other question does the best possible job of laying out the level of information anyone can have. There is also an XY problem here, in that you've titled the question regarding when applications are reviewed, but are really asking about adding to a CV after submission.

Comment: I think it is not reasonable to assume that the entire process starts after Christmas; there is no malicious intent of having a Dec 1st deadline.